# getting a "need project id error" in Keen

Tags: keen-io

I get the following error:

```
Keen.delete(:iron_worker_analytics, filters: [{:property_name => 'start_time', :operator => 'eq', :property_value => '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'}])

Keen::ConfigurationError: Keen IO Exception: Project ID must be set
```

However, when I set the value, I get the following:

```
 warning: already initialized constant KEEN_PROJECT_ID
 iron.io/env.rb:36: warning: previous definition of KEEN_PROJECT_ID was here
```

Keen works fine when I run the app and load the values from a `env.rb` file but from the console I cannot get past this.

I am using the ruby gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The documentation is confusing.  Per the documentation:

https://github.com/keenlabs/keen-gem

> The recommended way to set keys is via the environment. The keys you
>   can set are KEEN_PROJECT_ID, KEEN_WRITE_KEY, KEEN_READ_KEY and
>   KEEN_MASTER_KEY. You only need to specify the keys that correspond to
>   the API calls you'll be performing. If you're using foreman, add this
>   to your .env file:
>
> KEEN_PROJECT_ID=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
>   KEEN_MASTER_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   KEEN_WRITE_KEY=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy KEEN_READ_KEY=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz If not,
>   make a script to export the variables into your shell or put it before
>   the command you use to start your server.

But I had to set it explicitly as `Keen.project_id` after doing a `Keen.methods`.

It's sort of confusing since from the docs, I assumed I just need to set the variables.  Maybe I am misunderstanding the docs but it was confusing at least to me.